# Send notification on specific date and time

Tags: c#, push-notification, notifications

In our App, We are storing questions with Question's startdate, enddate and resultdate. We need to send notification to app (iPhone and Andorid) once startdate of question is arrives.

Can anybody let me know how can we achieve this?

We don't want to use pull method. like in particular time interval it will check for question startdate and send notification.

I have a URL to send Notification for question. I need to call this URL when question's startdate is arrived.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Quartz :

> Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems

[Quartz Enterprise Scheduler .NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)

You can create a new Quarts Job, lets call it *QuestionSenderJob*. Then your application can [schedule](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/simpletriggers.html) a task in Quartz scheduler, jobs can have many instances of same Job with custom data - in your case *QuestionId*.

Additionally it supports storing Job scheduling in your SQL database (there are DDL Scripts included) so you can create some relations if you need for UI for example.

> You can find table-creation SQL scripts in the "database/dbtables" directory of the Quartz.NET distribution

[Lesson 9: JobStores](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html)

This way you leave firing in right moment to Quartz engine.

When you will go through Quartz .NET basics, see this code snippet I made a for your case to schedule job. Perhaps some modifications will be necessary thought.

```
IDictionary<string, object> jobData = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "QuestionId", questionId } };
var questionDate = new DateTime(2016, 09, 01);
var questionTriggerName = string.Format("Question{0}_Trigger", questionId);
var questionTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity(questionTriggerName, "QuestionSendGroup")
    .StartAt(questionDate)
    .UsingJobData(new Quartz.JobDataMap(jobData))
    .Build();

scheduler
    .ScheduleJob(questionSenderJob, questionTrigger);
```

Then in Job you will get your questionId through JobExecutionContext.

```
public class QuestionSenderJob: IJob
{
    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {            
        JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;

        // Extract question Id and send message
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try this approach and send notification.

Comment: I updated an Answer to make it easier for you to move forward :)

Comment: Thanks Edgars, One more issue here is After application recycle (new deploy, regular recycle) it is lost all set scheduled jobs. is there a way to persist all job? I have tried to store in SQL as well.

Comment: Scheduled job is persistent by using SQL, i don't what mistake i done previously.. It is working fine.
I have created separate job for each each question notification, as questions having different startdate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)?

You do not want to use **pooling**, but if you write your own class that will encapsulate Timer (e.g. **System.Thread.Timer**) and check for the time each second, that will not take much resources. Depending on how exact you need it, you could check also less often, e.g. each minute. Maybe you should reconsider it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any third party service to manage your push notification such as Azure Notification Hub, Parse.com, ... they offer an integrated way to schedule push notifications. Either by passing in a send date or let them run a job periodically. I'm a user of the Azure service and it works very well.

Comment: This is the best approach, but as I am not sending notification from azure, so it will be more time consuming for me to update my code to send notification from azure.

Answer (score 0):

The best implementation i can advice right now is for you to send the notification from a server.
All you just need is a good scheduler that can dispatch operation.

For me, my server is powered by Javascript (NodeJS) so i use "node-schedule". All i just do is

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

//Reporting rule at minute 1 every hour
    var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
    rule.minute = 1;
schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function () {
    console.log(new Date().toTimeString() + ' Testing Scheduler! Executing Every other minute');
//sendPush()
});
```